# Nesting COUNTIF AND ISNUMBER

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to determine whether or not a list of PO #'s are in a list w/ multiple criteria. (1) criteria I am checking for is a direct match and I'm using the COUNTIF function. The other criteria I need to check for is whether or not the PO # starts with a letter (as all of these belong to our contract). Any ideas on how to check for both criteria? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Sample data and the expected result would be helpful here.

Comment: please mock up some data and expected output.